# How should I test this code with rspec rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rails application I have a module with an API call that I would like to write rspec tests for. What would you write as proper tests for this? I have read not to combine httparty with rspec because it is very slow and now I have no idea how to do this. Thanks for the advice!

```
module BandsInTown
  class API
    attr_reader :artist_name, :info, :events

    def initialize(artist_name)
        @artist_name = artist_name
    end

    def artist_info
        @info = fetch_data
    end

    def artist_events
        @events = fetch_data 'events'
    end

    private

    def fetch_data(endpoint = nil)
        request_url = "http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/#{[@artist_name, endpoint].compact.join('/')}.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=AUTH_KEY"
        resp = HTTParty.get(request_url)
        return false if resp.code != 200
        resp
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to get around making API requests.

Here's an example on how the code in yout `spec_helper.rb` could look like:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'

def stub_api_requests
  response = File.read('spec/fixtures/payload.json')
  stub_request(:get, %r{http:\/\/api.bandsintown.com\/artists/\/(.)*})
    .to_return(
      status: 200,
      body: response
    )
end

config.before(:each) do
  stub_api_requests
end
```

Comment: Thanks Vasile, this would go in the spec_helper but what would go in the rspec test itself?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Just test the methods as usual. You have control over the response with webmock.

Comment: Yeah got it now! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped could you please upvote it, or select it as the best answer. If not, let me know how I can make it more clear.